# Can't find base class for Mapview

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkannotation

I am trying to inherit from MKPinAnnotation in this manner:

MKPinAnnotationView -->MyPoint-->PhotoPoint

but I get an error in Xcode saying PhotoPoint can't be defined without a base class.

Here is my code in MyPoint.h:

```
#import <MapKit/MKPinAnnotationView.h>
@interface MyPoint:NSObject<MKAnnotation>{...}
```

then in PhotoPoint.h:

```
@interface PhotoPoint:MyPoint
```

and this is where I get the error...does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: please consider mark your question with properly tag!
Anyway...
http://mralek.se/post/9591337792/easy-custom-mkpinannotationview-with-pin-drop

Comment: Are you trying to create a class for your annotation _model_ objects (id<MKAnnotation>) or are you really trying to create a custom subclass of MKPinAnnotationView for your annotation _views_?

Comment: I just want to change the pin color depending if it is Photopoint of MyPoint so I subclass the MKPinAnnotationView..but now my code just exploded!

Comment: Have you implemented the viewForAnnotation delegate method?  If so, please show that code (add the code to the question).

Comment: @user3036511: It looks like PhotoPoint and MyPoint are classes that implement MKAnnotation (ie. they are your annotation model objects).  It doesn't make sense to make them "inherit from MKPinAnnotationView".  You don't need to inherit or subclass MKPinAnnotationView just to set the pinColor.  As I've mentioned, this is most easily done in the viewForAnnotation delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

In PhotoPoint.h you need to import MyPoint.h.

```
#import "MyPoint.h"

@interface PhotoPoint : MyPoint
```